# remove hidden table and publish new search result contents

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have a hidden div that I'm able to show after a user runs a search from my postgres database.  The problem I'm having, though, is that the div displays the first search results and won't update for subsequent searches.  It's just fixed on the first search result.  What jquery code do I need to add, so the search results reflect the new search? I'd like this to look just like a traditional search engine, where it's blank at the start, but keeps updating upon new search entries. Also, when I remove `return false;' it just flashes the results for a second, but won't keep them on the page.

**HTML SEARCH**

```
<%=search_form_for @search, url: user_path(current_user) do |f| %>
 <div class="actions" id="search"><%= f.submit "Search" %></div>
```

**Jquery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('#search').on('click', function(event) {        
             $('#results').removeAttr("style")
             return false;
        });
    });
```

**HTML DIV**

```
<div id='results' style="display: none;">
<table>
  <tr>
     <th><%= sort_link @search, :Plan_Name, "Plan Name" %></th>
     <th><%= sort_link @search, :Filing_Method, "Filing Method" %></th>
     <th><%= sort_link @search, :Participants, "Participants" %></th>
     <th><%= sort_link @search, :Filing_Type, "Filing Type" %></th>
</tr>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First add the "remote: true" setting to your form so it submits via ajax:

```
<%=search_form_for @search, url: user_path(current_user), remote: true do |f| %>
 <div class="actions" id="search"><%= f.submit "Search" %></div>
```

Add a div to your user view where the search is performed with an id of search results:

```
<div id='search-results'></div> <!-- This will be the div where your table of results is appended -->
```

Then, add a file named "user_search.js.erb" inside the users view folder with the following line:

```
$("#search-results").html("<%=escape_javascript(render 'search_results')%>").hide().fadeIn(900);
```

Then add a file named '_search_results.html.erb' to the same view folder the search is in(this is your partial that will be shown upon search.  Make sure to keep the leading '_').  In that file add your results table:

```
<div id='results' style="display: none;">
<table>
  <tr>
     <th><%= sort_link @search, :Plan_Name, "Plan Name" %></th>
     <th><%= sort_link @search, :Filing_Method, "Filing Method" %></th>
     <th><%= sort_link @search, :Participants, "Participants" %></th>
     <th><%= sort_link @search, :Filing_Type, "Filing Type" %></th>
</tr>
</div>
```

Then add to your route file:

```
get 'user_search', to: users#user_search, as: 'user_search'
```

Then in your users controller add:

```
def user_search
  @results = WhateverModelQueryYouHave
  respond_to do |format|
     format.html {}
     format.js { } #This is basically saying call for user_search.js.erb 
  end
end
```

You can also remove the jquery you originally had.

Comment: thanks bkunzi01.  One question regarding the user_search method.   @results = WhateverModelQueryYouHave, I'm unclear what syntax  I'm supposed to replace with WhateverModelQueryYouHave.  I'm searching a model called 'five' and this search fitler was set-up using the ransack gem.

Comment: Hey basically you just need to set an instance variable with your results so that you can access them in your view.  Whatever results the ransack gem returns you just want to pass it to your view (normally through an instance variable as shown by setting @results ).

Comment: thanks for your help bkunzi01, but I just couldn't get this to work.  Now, when I hit search, it does nothing.  I'll go back and review again and see if I can figure this out.  Appreciate your help.

Comment: Follow a "rails ajax" tutorial and it will show you how to deal with asynchronous requests etc. and once you do it you'll find it very easy!